Multiple realizability - Why can we just categorize mental states?
I am unable to understand why we can label mental states. Intuitively I would think that no two mental states are equal. My mental state when I was happy 2 weeks a ago was not the same as when I was happy today. The state of happiness was not identical, nor can I fathom how any two mental states I have can ever be identical.
From my understanding of type-identity theory I also do not understand why this kind of labeling is even necessary. If mental states are equal to brain states, then unless there is some proof that total brain states repeat throughout a persons life, I don't see why this would even be relevant.
Because of this I cannot understand how multiple realizability can be a thing either.
I know zero neurobiology though, so I apologize if all of this is obvious stuff.

Was the difference between your happy states greater or lesser in magnitude than the difference of the average between them and your average state of sadness?  And if you didn't label them, how would we know what you are asking about?

See my other comment. I get what you are saying, but I was not really asking with regards to a general context. I probably worded myself quite badly in the post i guess.

Type identity theory is a physicalist reductive theory to try to explain the mental from the physical. While here it seems that you’re subtly confusing categorization of the Aristotlian genera with reification onto haecceity of your mental states grasped with your own mental states…

The same way we can label a group of animals as cats, though no two cats are identical. They share enough characteristics that we group them together for purposes of convenience and discussion, then distinguish how they differ if and when that is relevant.
This is imperfect. Category errors are certainly possible. Different people will draw the lines in different places. If you need finer understanding, you need to discuss in greater detail. But for many purposes (I am a better cat owner than I am a dog owner), the more general statement is entirely sufficient.
The universe is fractal, fuzzy, and poorly defined. Accepting some generalizations and imperfections is how we normally deal with that.
(Question from the MIT freshman quiz: "Define the universe. Give three examples.")

I mainly find it weird/lacking in the context of multiple realizability or type-identity theory. If we just lump things together, then obviously that category of things can be realized in multiple ways.

I can't speak to those contexts. Maybe someone else can.

+1 - we usually define categories in a way that is stable to "irrelevant" differences. The key is in how we define our "relevancy function" F.  If we let Z be the set of physical states and F(z) being a function from z |-> {0,1}, then each such F selects a subset of Z as its preimage. That's how we get stable categories.

This goes to Wittgenstein's notion of 'family resemblances': things that we categorize as having an essential common feature may instead merely have multiple overlapping points of similarity with no specific feature common to all. There are no characteristics that are identical; there is only a loose but recognizable trend in a given direction. And moreover, these categories are public (social) in nature. We only make them because it's useful as a matter of communication and coordination with others.
In other words, mental states like anger, happiness, lust, greed, loyalty, etc., are distinguished not because they are (or are not) specific brain states, but because other people need words to describe our inner mental state in order to understand and predict our actions. Anger is that which leads to certain kinds of actions; happiness that which leads to other kinds of actions; lust that which leads to still other kinds of actions… We cannot know the mind of another, and so we look at their behavior and make a best guess; and likewise, we tell people that we are angry or happy or lustful so that they can know what to expect from us.
We label mental states because we have to; living with others demands it.


Because of this I cannot understand how multiple realizability can be a thing either.

Well, it is a theory, or an idea; nobody says that you need to subscribe to the concept or that it has any particular foot in reality, or any explanatory power beyond being a fun mind-game for philosophers.
Reading the SEP entry on Multiple Realizability (and fully acknowledging that a cursory glance over that page is all I know about it) I get the impression that the idea is at least partly simply a strategy for arguing about physicalism; i.e. an attempt at reductio ad absurdum by at least some philosophers.

Many philosophers have asserted that a wide variety of physical properties, states, or events, sharing no features in common at that level of description, can all realize the same pain. [...]
The multiple realizability contention about the mental is that a given psychological kind (like pain) can be realized by many distinct physical kinds: by different brain states in earthly biological pain-bearers, by electronic states in properly programmed digital computers, by green slime states in imagined extraterrestrials, and so on. [...]
After more than fifty years of detailed philosophical discussion there still seems to be no end in sight for novel ideas about this persistent concern.

There you go. You are not the only person confused about the concept. The whole line of reasoning can be attacked at many angles, and nobody seems to be quite sure what to make of it.
To answer at least part of your question:

Intuitively I would think that no two mental states are equal.

That is correct; it is unlikely bordering on impossible to have two exactly equal states in two different points in time – simply because there are so many possible permutations, both when looking at the abstraction level of the mind, and that of the brain.
Labeling mental states is still perfectly reasonable since a label is not an identifying name for enumerating the complete state of your mind and your brain at a moment of time. A label is a category, and categories are allowed to be as coarse or fine as necessary for whatever we use them for.
In the broadest sense, almost every human will agree that there are certain very broad states of mind (e.g. different levels of contentment, confusion, pain, hunger, thirst, happiness, wonder, whatever you can think of) without going any deeper. The whole point of categorization is to simplify the thing we're talking about.
The question of identity over time (in the Ship of Theseus sense) is completely different from that. The Ship is a Ship even after being completely replaced many times over, and it would make perfect sense to talk about many identical labels or categories of the Ship staying exactly the same, no matter how fine-grained the replacements are. For example, one could replace the complete ship so not a single atom is the same, and still have it fit these labels or propositions at any point of time:

The object is something vaguely recognizable as a ship to contemporary humans.
The object is made primarily of wood.
The object is used by people familiar with traveling on an ocean.
The object is man-made.
The object is floating when dropped into water.

The same is true for human mental state: stop drinking for two days, and you will be in a state that you would label deftly as "end-stage thirst", no matter how often you repeat it, no matter how many years are between experiments, no matter how many other details about your mental state have changed. It would not matter that you also stubbed your toe on a piece of Lego at one time and had a little pain from that, and not so at another time.
